# Parse .less files downloaded asynchronously

Tags: css, less

I'm using less for a web-app. In development environment, I have something like

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="test.less"/>       
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.0.2/less.min.js" ></script>
</head>
```

this is working correctly: my test.less file is downloaded and converted into valid css by less, automatically.

Now, If the user navigate in a particular section of the site, I need to download another .less file. To do so, I create a  element on the fly like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="test2.less"/>
```

and append it to the head.

This is NOT working - at least in Chrome 66.0.3359.117 - because the browser is not triggering the file download at all.

I resolved the problem by modifying the link 'rel' attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.less"/>
```

This way, the browser correctly download the file test2.less; however, it's content is not automatically parsed by less, so it is not converted to valid .css

I think that when less.js is downloaded, it executes by searchings all  element with attribute rel = "stylesheet/less" and parsing them - stop.

But after then, it "stops" listening to other .less files downloaded asynchronously.

There is a way to "trigger" less parsing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so far I've found a solution.

I bet there are more efficient solutions, but for now I'll proceed this way.

I append the element

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="test2.less"/>
```

in the head of the document, and this is not triggering the file download.

After that, I call the function

```
less.registerStylesheets().then(less.refresh);
```

This is causing less to read again the document, ask for all documents and parsing again them all... not efficient, but it works.

I wonder if exist a method to tell to less to import just a single file...

Edit: a small improvement:

instead of doing

```
less.registerStylesheets().then(less.refresh);
```

I can do

```
less.sheets.push(link);
less.refresh();
```

link is the reference to the link created. This way less won't read again all the document, searching for links; instead, it will just prepare the XHR for the new link created and parse that.